# bootsrapValidator is not defined error while trying to add custom validation method

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

having trouble adding a custom validator to the bootstrap validation at: [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js)

I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrapValidator is not defined" error while loading the page

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // custom validators
        bootstrapValidator.Validator.sin = {
            validate: function(validator, $field, options) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        $('#client_information_form').bootstrapValidator({
            framework: bootstrap,
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {

                c1_sin: {
                    validators: {
                        sin: {
                            message: "Invalid Social Insurance Number (SIN)"
                        },
                    }
                },
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
            $('#client_information_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(e.target);
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: On which line is the error coming from?

Comment: the first instance of:  bootstrapValidator.Validator.sin  - if I remove that everything works fine.